# Discord webhook + python отправляется дважды

Tags: python, discord.py, discord, discord-api

**Я уже час не могу решить проблему. Мой скрипт отправляет 2 embed, но приходят 3. Первое дублируется 2 раза.**
[image: Скриншот проблемы]

```
embed = DiscordEmbed(title="Текущий курс VDC", description='Vovadam Coin', color='ff00b7') 
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://avatars.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/6eafc3d1316b8f2b38098256061483e6e21026cd_full.jpg") 
    embed.add_embed_field(name='Value', value=vdc, inline=False) # Добавляет ключ и значение в тело сообщения, может быть на одной линии или нет.
    embed.set_footer(text='[Jesus42]', icon_url="https://avatars.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/6eafc3d1316b8f2b38098256061483e6e21026cd_full.jpg") 
    webhook.add_embed(embed) 
    webhook.execute()
    
    embed = DiscordEmbed(title="Текущий курс HRP", description='HappyRP Coin', color='ff00b7') 
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://avatars.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/6eafc3d1316b8f2b38098256061483e6e21026cd_full.jpg") 
    embed.add_embed_field(name='Value', value=hrp, inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text='[Jesus42]', icon_url="https://avatars.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/6eafc3d1316b8f2b38098256061483e6e21026cd_full.jpg") 
    webhook.add_embed(embed) 
    webhook.execute()
```

Comment: Ничего не знаю про библиотеку, но выглядит так, что webhook ведет себя как контейнер, и вы добавляете в него 1, делаете [1].execute. А потом добавляете 2, получатся [1, 2].execute. Примерно мысль ясна?

Comment: Если честно. то нет (я про мысль, я тупой). Они одинаковые, но один из них отправляется два раза.

Comment: execute по виду как раз отправляет сообщения. Посмотрите в самом дискорде - это же вроде два сообщения? Первое - с первым эмбедом. Второе - с первым и вторым эмбедами.

Comment: СПАСИБО! Действительно, теперь понял!